# Radon space and Polish space.

Tags: linear-algebra

This should be simple but could not understand. This refers to the link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space

where it mentions that: Lusin spaces, Suslin spaces, and Radon spaces are generalizations of Polish spaces.

I did not understand why it is said as generalization. Would you please point out what I am missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $P$ and $Q$ are possible properties of some class $\mathscr{C}$ of mathematical objects, we say that $P$ generalizes $Q$ if every object with property $Q$ also has property $P$. In other words, the class of objects in $\mathscr{C}$ having property $Q$ is a subclass of the class of objects in $\mathscr{C}$ having property $P$. Unless the properties are actually equivalent, this means that there are objects in $\mathscr{C}$ that have $P$ but not $Q$: the property $P$ characterizes a larger, more general class of objects than does the property $Q$.

Here the objects are topological spaces. Let $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ be a topological space.

- $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is Lusin if there is some topology $\tau'\subseteq\tau$ such that $\langle X,\tau'\rangle$ is Polish; if $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is already Polish, then we can take $\tau'=\tau$, so every Polish space is automatically a Lusin space.
- $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is Suslin if there are a Polish space $\langle Y,\tau'\rangle$ and a continuous surjection $f:Y\to X$. If $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is already Polish, we may take $Y=X$ and $\tau'=\tau$, so every Polish space is automatically a Suslin space.
- Finally, every Suslin space is known to be a Radon space, meaning that every finite Borel measure on it is inner regular, and we’ve already seen that every Polish space is Suslin, so every Polish space is Radon.

Thus, the properties of being Lusin, Suslin, or Radon are more general than the property of being Polish: every Polish space is Lusin, Suslin, and Radon, but there are Lusin (Suslin, Radon, resp.) spaces that are not Polish. A result that is true of all Lusin spaces, for instance, is more general than one that is true merely of all Polish spaces, because it holds also for the Lusin spaces that are not Polish.

Comment: @Creator: You’re very welcome.

Comment: I think, there is a mistake in Wikipedia. A space $X$ is called Lusin if there is a bijective continuous map $f : Y \to X$ from a Polish space $Y$. Equivalently, $X$ is Lusin if there is a **stronger** topology $\tau' \supseteq \tau$ on $X$ under which $X$ is Polish.